# Dynamically changing state vue

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

For my application I am using Vue-router and store to work together. In my state I am storing a few questions. The content of the questions is saved in my Store like so:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    blabla: [
      {
        question: 'question1',
        answer: false,
        givenAnswer: null,
        disabled: false,
      },
      {
        question: 'question2',
        answer: false,
        givenAnswer: null,
        disabled: false
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  getters: {
    getQuestionList: state => {
      return state.questions;
    }
  })
```

And of course with othe config, but this all works fine. I am getting this data through a Getter in my Vue template by using this code in my Component:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      questionId: this.$route.params.id - 1
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getQuestions () {
      return this.$store.getters.getQuestionList
    }
  }
}
```

```
<p>{{ getQuestions[questionId].question }}</p>
```

Now I want to dynamically mutate the state of every question to `disabled:false` whenever someone answers the question in order to enable answering the next question. However I can not figure out how to exactly do it.

Can someone put me in the right direction? Thanks!

**Edit for clarification:** There is a list of 10 questions and when you start, only the first one is enabled at the start. When you answer question 1, question 2 should be enabled (question one also stays enabled), when you answer question 2, question 3 should be enabled, etc.

Comment: Hi Farallo, welcome to S/O. Your question is reasonable, but needs to be improved - generally stackoverflow questions need to be specific and concise. Please consider revising it and making it clear that you read the vuex docs and at least tried something on your own. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just commit a mutation that sets `disabled: false` for the specified element:

#### Cmponent

```html
<button @click="submitQuestion(question.id)"></button>
```

```js
methods: {
  submitQuestion (id) {
    // ...
    this.$store.commit('ENABLE_QUESTION', id + 1) // passing id of the next question
  }
}
```

#### Store

```js
state: {
  questions: [
    {
      id: 0,
      question: 'question1',
      answer: false,
      givenAnswer: null,
      disabled: false,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      question: 'question2',
      answer: false,
      givenAnswer: null,
      disabled: false
    }
  ]
}

...

mutations: {
  ENABLE_QUESTION (state, id) {
    let questionIndex = state.questions.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
    state.questions[questionIndex].disabled = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. However it's not what I meant. There is a list of 10 questions and when you start, only the first one is enabled at the start. When you answer question 1, question 2 should be enabled (question one also stays enabled), when you answer question 2, question 3 should be enabled, etc.

Comment: @Farallo I edited the answer. Add `id` property to the question objects and then pass that `id` into the mutation

Answer (score -1):

in your store put this mutation code :

```
mutations: {
    enable (state) {
    state.questions.forEach(item => {
      item.disabled = false
    )}
  }
}
```

and in your component you can commit this mutation easily as follows:

```
this.$store.commit('enable')
```